# How to upload image into sqlite db in android and view it?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android development. And I want to make a photo sharing application so that once the application is installed on the android device the user can upload his/her image.
I have seen a lot of examples but nothing works for me. Please help I am newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Storing images in db is a bad solution.

The best approach is to store your images into phone file system, while storing the file path in db. In this way, you can get the original image file looking at its file path retrived by your database query.

Whatever, if you MUST save your images in db, you can check this useful tutorial:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database

Comment: I know this thing , so please give me an example code for storing image path in spite of storing image itself.